# ProPlayer : Embedding this video is disabled by its owner

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using ProPlayer Video Plugin in my WordPress blog.  When I clicked in the video, it displays **Embedding this video is disabled by its owner**
When I individually open the video link in URL it plays well. 
I guess its the problem of ProPlayer Plugin. 
Can you suggest me to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Tried but could not find the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the underlying JW Player.

YouTube made a move from AS2 to AS3, the jw player version needs to be downgraded to get videos to play ([source](http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/17773/a-word-about-youtube-support-in-the-jw-player)).

Hopefully this plugin dev can offer a solution to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the answer is in the question title itself: embedding was **disabled**.

You don't mention what site is hosting the video, but YouTube *(Allow others to embed your video in their sites)* and Vimeo *(Do not allow anyone to embed this video)* have this feature.

Your only option is writing to the video owner and ask "Could you please enable the embedding of your video?"

Comment: Thanks Brasofilo for the suggestion.